# SAXParser Error while trying to parse Xml from a remote server in Android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, sax, saxparser

I am trying to parse `xml` from a remote [server](http://www.connectingtomorrow.co.uk/xmlFiles/accounts.xml).

My codes for 3 `java` programs are below:
**1. BillScreen.java:**

```
package cc3012n.kalrashid;

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BillScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

     String baseURL = "http://www.connectingtomorrow.co.uk/xmlFiles/accounts.xml";
     TextView tv;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         Button b = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bGo);
         tv = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvXML);

         b.setOnClickListener(this);
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         try {
             URL website = new URL(baseURL);
             SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
             SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
             XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
             HandlingXMLStuff doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
             xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
             xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
             String information = doingWork.getInformation();
             tv.setText(information);
         } catch(Exception e){
             tv.setText("error");
         }
     }  
}
```

**2. Handling XML Stuff:**

```
package cc3012n.kalrashid;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler {

    XMLDataCollected info = new XMLDataCollected();

    public String getInformation() {
        return info.dataToString();
    }

     @Override
     public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
         Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (localName.equals("customer_id")) {
          String customer = attributes.getValue("data");
          info.setCustomer(customer);
      } else if (localName.equals("table_id")) {
          String table = attributes.getValue("data");
          info.setTable(table);
      }
    }
}
```

**3. XMLDataCollected.java:**

```
public class XMLDataCollected {

    String customer = null;
    String table = null;

    public void setCustomer (String ac){
        customer = ac;
    }

    public void setTable(String tbl){
        table = tbl; 
    }

    public String dataToString(){
        return customer + " In table Number " +table;
    }
}
```

But it's returning an error.. so it's not being able to read the `xml` file .. would you kindly tell me what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show the stacktrace with the error.  In order to do that, you will have to remove your catchall exception clause, which is bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the permission for internet access.
Try to add the folowing line in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: it doesn´t cause : SAXParser Error